# How to check if GQL object is empty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

I'm trying to check if a GQL object is empty or not (in Google App Engine using Python), how should I do it?
I tried this but it didn't work:

```
comments = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                                "FROM Comment "
                                "where ANCESTOR IS :1 "
                                "order by date DESC", 
                                movie_data) 
        if comments:
            ratingsum = 0
            i=0
            for comment in comments:
                ratingsum=ratingsum + comment.rating
                i+=1
            average = ratingsum/i
        else:
            average = "no ratings"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Gql query gives you a query object, but not the results (the entities). To get the results you have to fetch the results : using fetch, count, get or iterate through the result set.

Answer (score 0):

[According to @NickJohnson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1943938/190597), calling `count` would require executing the same query twice. So to avoid that, and since you are going to have to iterate through the comments, you might as well "detect" when the comments are empty by observing a side-effect -- that `i` would be zero if `comments` is empty:

```
comments = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                                "FROM Comment "
                                "where ANCESTOR IS :1 "
                                "order by date DESC", 
                                movie_data) 
ratingsum = 0
i = 0
for comment in comments:
    ratingsum += comment.rating
    i += 1
if i:    
    average = ratingsum/i
else:    
    average = "no ratings"
```